# Space between ng-repeat getting error

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the value in array with space between words getting error i replace the space the issue will be fixed but in U.I I want to show it in space.

code

```
<td ng-repeat="measure in subsystem.measures track by $index" ng-show={{measure.measureType}}>
      <h4><b>{{measure.measureType}}</b> </h4>
</td>
```

Value: EB Bill`

Error:

```
[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Bill' is an unexpected token at column 5 of the expression [EB Bill] starting at [Bill].
```

Comment: show some sample data, issue doesn't make sense

Comment: why not use css class to bring about the gap?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on `ng-show` which should evaluate to trusy...however 'EB Bill' doesn't evaluate to anything. If you remove the `ng-show` directive, then it should work...see below...

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("testcontroller", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    //$scope.measure.measureType = "EB Bill";
    $scope.subsystem = {
      measures: [{
        measureType: 'one'
      }, {
        measureType: 'two and three'
      }, {
        measureType: 'EB Bill'
      }]
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testcontroller">
  <div ng-repeat="measure in subsystem.measures track by $index">
    <h4><b>{{measure.measureType}}</b> </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's NOT how `ng-show`  work...it simple evaluates an expression, if the expression is trusy the element is shown, if the expression evaluates to falsy then the expression is NOT shown...

Answer (score 1):

> You must have true or false value for ng-show, Try to have only true or false data for measureType property, I am sure you will not get this error.